# Quantstrat: apply.paramset fails due to combine error for certain paramater distributions, but not others

Tags: r, quantstrat

For some reason when I adjust the paramater distributions for `apply.paramaset` to include more extreme values beyond about `-250` **I get a simpleError saying**

> match.names(clabs,names(xi)) names do not match previous names

Sometimes this error doesn't occur when I do a very low sample size with the problem distributions but that may just be because specific paramater combos causing the problem aren't tried.

What I don't get is what arguments are being fed to match.names and where which could results in this error for some paramater combinations, but not others. The other odd thing about this problem is that it does not happen on the symbol I originally was working with, but when I try the system on other symbols it begins to occur.

Comment: I doubt there is enough code or details to offer a specific answer.

Comment: please provide code samples that other users can run locally to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No results from apply.paramset if one parameter combination returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987166/no-results-from-apply-paramset-if-one-parameter-combination-returns-nothing)